# merge_asof equivalent using pandas merge only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have the following 2 DataFrames. A has the data and B has the weights for the data. B has the dates on which the weights become active as the index and 'level_1' has the entity for which the weight is relevant.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-15', periods=10, freq='B'))
B = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='W'))
A["X"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Y"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Z"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])


B["X"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Y"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Z"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])

A = A.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)
B = B.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)
```

I want to end up with something like this at the end (which is equivalent to A with the weights in B applied in the 'weight' column)

```
           level_1         0    weight
2016-01-15       X  0.456115    0.853601
2016-01-15       Y  0.849457    0.420065
2016-01-15       Z  0.216661    0.767833
2016-01-18       X  0.434117    0.165397
2016-01-18       Y  0.914670    0.338894
2016-01-18       Z  0.107617    0.130946
2016-01-19       X  0.575688    0.165397
2016-01-19       Y  0.147352    0.338894
2016-01-19       Z  0.950299    0.130946
2016-01-20       X  0.637323    0.165397
2016-01-20       Y  0.793915    0.338894
2016-01-20       Z  0.072430    0.130946
2016-01-21       X  0.991307    0.165397
2016-01-21       Y  0.685731    0.338894
2016-01-21       Z  0.889280    0.130946
2016-01-22       X  0.671650    0.165397
2016-01-22       Y  0.550121    0.338894
2016-01-22       Z  0.682943    0.130946
2016-01-25       X  0.660611    0.245470
2016-01-25       Y  0.146163    0.277813
2016-01-25       Z  0.219939    0.552831
2016-01-26       X  0.288662    0.245470
2016-01-26       Y  0.871490    0.277813
2016-01-26       Z  0.340407    0.552831
2016-01-27       X  0.416167    0.245470
2016-01-27       Y  0.274234    0.277813
2016-01-27       Z  0.686227    0.552831
2016-01-28       X  0.275956    0.245470
2016-01-28       Y  0.804975    0.277813
2016-01-28       Z  0.664723    0.552831
```

What trips me up is that the indices in B are not (or not necessarily) in A which means I cannot just add the data in B to A under a column then do A['weights'].fillna(method='ffill'). I can loop over I guess but this is slow and messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
np.random.seed(1234)
A = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-15', periods=10, freq='B'))
B = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='W'))
A["X"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Y"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Z"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])


B["X"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Y"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Z"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])

A = A.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)
B = B.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)

#print (A)
#print (B)
```

```
print (pd.merge_asof(A.reset_index(),
                     B.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'weight'}), on='index', by='level_1'))

       index level_1         0    weight
0  2016-01-15       X  0.191519  0.436173
1  2016-01-15       Y  0.357817  0.218792
2  2016-01-15       Z  0.364886  0.184287
3  2016-01-18       X  0.622109  0.802148
4  2016-01-18       Y  0.500995  0.924868
5  2016-01-18       Z  0.615396  0.047355
6  2016-01-19       X  0.437728  0.802148
7  2016-01-19       Y  0.683463  0.924868
8  2016-01-19       Z  0.075381  0.047355
9  2016-01-20       X  0.785359  0.802148
10 2016-01-20       Y  0.712702  0.924868
11 2016-01-20       Z  0.368824  0.047355
12 2016-01-21       X  0.779976  0.802148
13 2016-01-21       Y  0.370251  0.924868
14 2016-01-21       Z  0.933140  0.047355
15 2016-01-22       X  0.272593  0.802148
16 2016-01-22       Y  0.561196  0.924868
17 2016-01-22       Z  0.651378  0.047355
18 2016-01-25       X  0.276464  0.143767
19 2016-01-25       Y  0.503083  0.442141
20 2016-01-25       Z  0.397203  0.674881
21 2016-01-26       X  0.801872  0.143767
22 2016-01-26       Y  0.013768  0.442141
23 2016-01-26       Z  0.788730  0.674881
24 2016-01-27       X  0.958139  0.143767
25 2016-01-27       Y  0.772827  0.442141
26 2016-01-27       Z  0.316836  0.674881
27 2016-01-28       X  0.875933  0.143767
28 2016-01-28       Y  0.882641  0.442141
29 2016-01-28       Z  0.568099  0.674881
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I'm using an older version of pandas. Is there a way to do this with pandas.merge() rather than pandas.merge_asof()? I've been trying to without any success.

Comment: No, it is new function in pandas `0.19.0` and no similar function was before. Unfortunately.

Comment: I managed to get a version with only pandas.merge(). It's more elaborate than merge_asof() and probably a lot slower. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction to use merge().

Answer (score 0):

OK, I developed another solution after the pivotal note that jezrael gave me (use merge). This uses only pandas.merge() to do the task above

```
A = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-15', periods=10, freq='B'))
B = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', periods=5, freq='W'))
A["X"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Y"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
A["Z"] = np.random.rand(A.shape[0])


B["X"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Y"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])
B["Z"] = np.random.rand(B.shape[0])

A = A.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)
B = B.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)

ss = pd.merge(A.reset_index(),B.reset_index(), how='outer', on="index", sort=True).set_index("index")
ss["level_1"] = ss["level_1_x"].fillna(ss["level_1_y"])
ss = ss.drop(["level_1_x", "level_1_y"], axis=1)
w = ss.reset_index().pivot(index='index', columns="level_1", values='0_y').ffill().stack(dropna=False).reset_index(level=1)

A['weight'] =  w[w.index.isin(A.index)][0]
```